# JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

```js
var funcs = [];
// let's create 3 functions
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // and store them in funcs
  funcs[i] = function() {
    // each should log its value.
    console.log("My value:", i);
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  // and now let's run each one to see
  funcs[j]();
}
```

It outputs this:

> My value: 3
> My value: 3
> My value: 3

Whereas I'd like it to output:

> My value: 0
> My value: 1
> My value: 2

---

The same problem occurs when the delay in running the function is caused by using event listeners:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
// let's create 3 functions
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  // as event listeners
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // each should log its value.
    console.log("My value:", i);
  });
}
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<br />
<button>1</button>
<br />
<button>2</button>
```

… or asynchronous code, e.g. using Promises:

```js
// Some async wait function
const wait = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // Log `i` as soon as each promise resolves.
  wait(i * 100).then(() => console.log(i));
}
```

It is also apparent in `for in` and `for of` loops:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3];
const fns = [];

for (var i in arr){
  fns.push(() => console.log("index:", i));
}

for (var v of arr){
  fns.push(() => console.log("value:", v));
}

for (const n of arr) {
  var obj = { number: n }; // or new MyLibObject({ ... })
  fns.push(() => console.log("n:", n, "|", "obj:", JSON.stringify(obj)));
}

for(var f of fns){
  f();
}
```

What’s the solution to this basic problem?

Comment: In **ES6**, a trivial solution is to declare the variable _i_ with [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), which is scoped to the body of the loop.

Comment: JS functions "close over" the scope they have access to upon declaration, and retain access to that scope even as variables in that scope change. Each function in the array above closes over the global scope (global, simply because that happens to be the scope they're declared in). Later those functions are invoked logging the most current value of `i` in the global scope. That's JS : ) `let` instead of `var` solves this by creating a new scope each time the loop runs, creating a separated scope for each function to close over. Various other techniques do the same thing with extra functions.

Answer (score 2401, accepted):

Well, the problem is that the variable `i`, within each of your anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the function.

## ES6 solution: `let`

ECMAScript 6 (ES6) introduces new `let` and `const` keywords that are scoped differently than `var`-based variables. For example, in a loop with a `let`-based index, each iteration through the loop will have a new variable `i` with loop scope, so your code would work as you expect. There are many resources, but I'd recommend [2ality's block-scoping post](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html) as a great source of information.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i] = function() {
    console.log("My value: " + i);
  };
}
```

Beware, though, that IE9-IE11 and Edge prior to Edge 14 support `let` but get the above wrong (they don't create a new `i` each time, so all the functions above would log 3 like they would if we used `var`). Edge 14 finally gets it right.

---

## ES5.1 solution: forEach

With the relatively widespread availability of the `Array.prototype.forEach` function (in 2015), it's worth noting that in those situations involving iteration primarily over an array of values, `.forEach()` provides a clean, natural way to get a distinct closure for every iteration. That is, assuming you've got some sort of array containing values (DOM references, objects, whatever), and the problem arises of setting up callbacks specific to each element, you can do this:

```
var someArray = [ /* whatever */ ];
// ...
someArray.forEach(function(arrayElement) {
  // ... code code code for this one element
  someAsynchronousFunction(arrayElement, function() {
    arrayElement.doSomething();
  });
});
```

The idea is that each invocation of the callback function used with the `.forEach` loop will be its own closure. The parameter passed in to that handler is the array element specific to that particular step of the iteration. If it's used in an asynchronous callback, it won't collide with any of the other callbacks established at other steps of the iteration.

If you happen to be working in jQuery, the `$.each()` function gives you a similar capability.

---

## Classic solution: Closures

What you want to do is bind the variable within each function to a separate, unchanging value outside of the function:

```js
var funcs = [];

function createfunc(i) {
  return function() {
    console.log("My value: " + i);
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i] = createfunc(i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  // and now let's run each one to see
  funcs[j]();
}
```

Since there is no block scope in JavaScript - only function scope - by wrapping the function creation in a new function, you ensure that the value of "i" remains as you intended.

Comment: isn't `function createfunc(i) {
    return function() { console.log("My value: " + i); };
}` still closure because it uses the variable `i`?

Comment: @Alex: Yes. All JavaScript functions create closures. The only question is the state of the closed-over variable that the function references. The solution creates a new variable scope upon invocation of `createfunc` that has both the `i` value at the time of invocation and a function that references that `i`. So each returned function (closure) is in its own scope closing over its own `i`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is outdated and nobody will see the correct answer at the bottom - using `Function.bind()` is definitely preferable by now, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323214/785541.

Comment: @Wladimir: Your suggestion that `.bind()` is *"the correct answer"* isn't right. They each have their own place. With `.bind()` you can't bind arguments without binding the `this` value. Also you get a copy of the `i` argument without the ability to mutate it between calls, which sometimes is needed. So they're quite different constructs, not to mention that `.bind()` implementations have been historically slow. Sure in the simple example either would work, but closures are an important concept to understand, and that's what the question was about.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, how `let` helps in capturing the values, and not references?

Comment: Please stop using these for-return function hacks, use [].forEach or [].map instead because they avoid reusing the same scope variables.

Comment: @ChristianLandgren: That's only useful if you're iterating an Array. These techniques aren't "hacks". They're essential knowledge.

Answer (score 423):

Try:

```js
var funcs = [];
    
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = (function(index) {
        return function() {
            console.log("My value: " + index);
        };
    }(i));
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
```

**Edit** (2014):

Personally I think @Aust's [more recent answer about using `.bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323214/918959) is the best way to do this kind of thing now. There's also lo-dash/underscore's `_.partial` when you don't need or want to mess with `bind`'s `thisArg`.

Comment: any explanation about the `}(i));` ?

Comment: @aswzen I think it passes `i` as the argument `index` to the function.

Comment: it is actually creating local variable index.

Comment: Immediately Invoke Function Expression, aka IIFE.  (i) is the argument to the anonymous function expression that is invoked immediately and index becomes set from i.

Answer (score 392):

Another way that hasn't been mentioned yet is the use of [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
var funcs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i] = function(x) {
    console.log('My value: ' + x);
  }.bind(this, i);
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();
}
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @squint and @mekdev, you get better performance by creating the function outside the loop first and then binding the results within the loop.

```js
function log(x) {
  console.log('My value: ' + x);
}

var funcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i] = log.bind(this, i);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();
}
```

Comment: This is what I do these days too, I also like lo-dash/underscore's `_.partial`

Comment: `.bind()` will be largely obsolete with ECMAScript 6 features. Besides, this actually creates two functions per iteration. First the anonymous, then the one generated by `.bind()`. Better use would be to create it outside the loop, then `.bind()` it inside.

Comment: Doesn't this trigger JsHint - Don't make functions within a loop. ?

I went down this path also but after running code quality tools its a no go..

Comment: @squint @mekdev - You both are correct. My initial example was written quickly to demonstrate how `bind` is used. I've added another example per your suggestions.

Comment: I think instead of wasting computation over two O(n) loops, just 
do

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    log.call(this, i);
}

Comment: .bind() does what the accepted answer suggests PLUS fiddles with `this`.

Answer (score 295):

Using an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), the simplest and most readable way to enclose an index variable:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    (function(index) {

        console.log('iterator: ' + index);
        //now you can also loop an ajax call here 
        //without losing track of the iterator value:   $.ajax({});
    
    })(i);

}
```

This sends the iterator `i` into the anonymous function of which we define as `index`.  This creates a closure, where the variable `i` gets saved for later use in any asynchronous functionality within the IIFE.

Comment: For further code readability and to avoid confusion as to which `i` is what, I'd rename the function parameter to `index`.

Comment: How would you use this technique to define the array *funcs* described in the original question?

Comment: @Nico The same way as shown in the original question, except you would use `index` instead of `i`.

Comment: @JLRishe `var funcs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = (function(index) {
        return function() {console.log('iterator: ' + index);};
    })(i);
};
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}`

Comment: @Nico `for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        funcs[index] = function () {
            console.log("My value: " + index);
        };
    })(i);
}`

Comment: @JLRishe, your version is better. I think, though, that we shouldn't recommend this answer; the use of [bind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19323214/918959) is simpler and more readable.

Comment: @Nico In the general case, yes `.bind()` is better, but when iterating over an array, `.forEach()` is almost always the best option.

Comment: @Nico In OP's particular case, they're just iterating over numbers, so this wouldn't be a great case for `.forEach()`, but a lot of the time, when one is starting off with an array, `forEach()` is a good choice, like: `var nums [4, 6, 7]; var funcs = {}; nums.forEach(function (num, i) { funcs[i] = function () { console.log(num); }; });`

Comment: @Nico Actually this example solved my specific issue where I for a single value needed to make an http request and needed to keep a reference for usage in the callback and .bind nor forEach was a clean solution.

Comment: i was looking for the syntax of immediately invoked function and couldn't figure it out. +1

Comment: @KyleFalconer why it is confusing? both `i` of the loop and `i` inside the function contains the same data.

Answer (score 184):

Bit late to the party, but I was exploring this issue today and noticed that many of the answers don't completely address how Javascript treats scopes, which is essentially what this boils down to.

So as many others mentioned, the problem is that the inner function is referencing the same `i` variable. So why don't we just create a new local variable each iteration, and have the inner function reference that instead?

```js
//overwrite console.log() so you can see the console output
console.log = function(msg) {document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';};

var funcs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var ilocal = i; //create a new local variable
    funcs[i] = function() {
        console.log("My value: " + ilocal); //each should reference its own local variable
    };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
```

Just like before, where each inner function outputted the last value assigned to `i`, now each inner function just outputs the last value assigned to `ilocal`. But shouldn't each iteration have it's own `ilocal`?

Turns out, that's the issue. Each iteration is sharing the same scope, so every iteration after the first is just overwriting `ilocal`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#No_block_scope):

> Important: JavaScript does not have block scope. Variables introduced with a block are scoped to the containing function or script, and the effects of setting them persist beyond the block itself. In other words, block statements do not introduce a scope. Although "standalone" blocks are valid syntax, you do not want to use standalone blocks in JavaScript, because they don't do what you think they do, if you think they do anything like such blocks in C or Java.

Reiterated for emphasis:

> ### JavaScript does not have block scope. Variables introduced with a block are scoped to the containing function or script

We can see this by checking `ilocal` before we declare it in each iteration:

```js
//overwrite console.log() so you can see the console output
console.log = function(msg) {document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';};

var funcs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(ilocal);
  var ilocal = i;
}
```

This is exactly why this bug is so tricky. Even though you are redeclaring a variable, Javascript won't throw an error, and JSLint won't even throw a warning. This is also why the best way to solve this is to take advantage of closures, which is essentially the idea that in Javascript, inner functions have access to outer variables because inner scopes "enclose" outer scopes.

[image: Closures]

This also means that inner functions "hold onto" outer variables and keep them alive, even if the outer function returns. To utilize this, we create and call a wrapper function purely to make a new scope, declare `ilocal` in the new scope, and return an inner function that uses `ilocal` (more explanation below):

```js
//overwrite console.log() so you can see the console output
console.log = function(msg) {document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';};

var funcs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = (function() { //create a new scope using a wrapper function
        var ilocal = i; //capture i into a local var
        return function() { //return the inner function
            console.log("My value: " + ilocal);
        };
    })(); //remember to run the wrapper function
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
```

Creating the inner function inside a wrapper function gives the inner function a private environment that only it can access, a "closure". Thus, every time we call the wrapper function we create a new inner function with it's own separate environment, ensuring that the `ilocal` variables don't collide and overwrite each other. A few minor optimizations gives the final answer that many other SO users gave:

```js
//overwrite console.log() so you can see the console output
console.log = function(msg) {document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';};

var funcs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = wrapper(i);
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
//creates a separate environment for the inner function
function wrapper(ilocal) {
    return function() { //return the inner function
        console.log("My value: " + ilocal);
    };
}
```

**Update**

With ES6 now mainstream, we can now use the new `let` keyword to create block-scoped variables:

```js
//overwrite console.log() so you can see the console output
console.log = function(msg) {document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>';};

var funcs = {};
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // use "let" to declare "i"
    funcs[i] = function() {
        console.log("My value: " + i); //each should reference its own local variable
    };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) { // we can use "var" here without issue
    funcs[j]();
}
```

Look how easy it is now! For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16661498/1852456), which my info is based off of.

Comment: There is now such a thing as block scoping in JavaScript using the `let` and `const` keywords. If this answer were to expand to include that, it would be much more globally useful in my opinion.

Comment: @TinyGiant sure thing, I added some info about `let` and linked a more complete explanation

Comment: @woojoo666 Could your answer also work for calling two alternating URL's in a loop like so: `i=0;
while(i < 100)
{
    setTimeout(function(){ window.open("https://www.bbc.com","_self") }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function(){ window.open("https://www.cnn.com","_self") }, 3000);
  i++
}`? (could replace window.open() with getelementbyid......)

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty sorry about such a late reply. It doesn't seem like the code in your example already works. You aren't using `i` in your timeout functions, so you don't need a closure

Comment: whoops, sorry, meant to say "it seems like the code in your example already works"

Answer (score 170):

With ES6 now widely supported, the best answer to this question has changed.  ES6 provides the `let` and `const` keywords for this exact circumstance.  Instead of messing around with closures, we can just use `let` to set a loop scope variable like this:

```js
var funcs = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {          
    funcs[i] = function() {            
      console.log("My value: " + i); 
    };
}
```

`val` will then point to an object that is specific to that particular turn of the loop, and will return the correct value without the additional closure notation.  This obviously significantly simplifies this problem.

`const` is similar to `let` with the additional restriction that the variable name can't be rebound to a new reference after initial assignment.

Browser support is now here for those targeting the latest versions of browsers. `const`/`let` are currently supported in the latest Firefox, Safari, Edge and Chrome. It also is supported in Node, and you can use it anywhere by taking advantage of build tools like Babel.  You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ben336/rbU4t/2/

Docs here:

- [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)
- [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Beware, though, that IE9-IE11 and Edge prior to Edge 14 support `let` but get the above wrong (they don't create a new `i` each time, so all the functions above would log 3 like they would if we used `var`). Edge 14 finally gets it right.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'let' is still not fully supported, especially in mobile. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: As of June '16, [let](http://caniuse.com/#search=let) is supported in all major browser versions except iOS Safari, Opera Mini and Safari 9. Evergreen browsers support it. Babel will transpile it correctly to keep the expected behaviour without high compliancy mode switched on.

Comment: @DanPantry yeah about time for an update :)  Updated to better reflect the current state of things, including adding a mention of const, doc links and better compatibility info.

Comment: Isn't this why we use babel to transpile our code so browsers that don't support ES6/7 can understand what's going on?

Answer (score 98):

Another way of saying it is that the `i` in your function is bound at the time of executing the function, not the time of creating the function.

When you create the closure, `i` is a reference to the variable defined in the outside scope, not a copy of it as it was when you created the closure. It will be evaluated at the time of execution.

Most of the other answers provide ways to work around by creating another variable that won't change the value for you.

Just thought I'd add an explanation for clarity. For a solution, personally, I'd go with Harto's since it is the most self-explanatory way of doing it from the answers here. Any of the code posted will work, but I'd opt for a closure factory over having to write a pile of comments to explain why I'm declaring a new variable(Freddy and 1800's) or have weird embedded closure syntax(apphacker).

Answer (score 80):

What you need to understand is the scope of the variables in javascript is based on the function. This is an important difference than say c# where you have block scope, and just copying the variable to one inside the for will work.

Wrapping it in a function that evaluates returning the function like apphacker's answer will do the trick, as the variable now has the function scope.

There is also a let keyword instead of var, that would allow using the block scope rule. In that case defining a variable inside the for would do the trick. That said, the let keyword isn't a practical solution because of compatibility.

```js
var funcs = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let index = i; //add this
  funcs[i] = function() {
    console.log("My value: " + index); //change to the copy
  };
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();
}
```

Comment: @nickf which browser? as I said, it has compatibility issues, with that I mean serious compatibility issues, like I don't think let is supported in IE.

Comment: @nickf yes, check this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/New_in_JavaScript_1.7 ... check the let definitions section, there is an onclick example inside a loop

Comment: @nickf hmm, actually you have to explicitly specify the version: <script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"/> ... I haven't actually used it anywhere because of the IE restriction, it just isn't practical :(

Comment: you can see browser support for the different versions here http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript

Comment: See also [What browsers currently support javascript's 'let' keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356830/what-browsers-currently-support-javascripts-let-keyword)

Answer (score 66):

Here's another variation on the technique, similar to Bjorn's (apphacker), which lets you assign the variable value inside the function rather than passing it as a parameter, which might be clearer sometimes:

```js
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = (function() {
        var index = i;
        return function() {
            console.log("My value: " + index);
        }
    })();
}
```

Note that whatever technique you use, the `index` variable becomes a sort of static variable, bound to the returned copy of the inner function. I.e., changes to its value are preserved between calls. It can be very handy.

Comment: Thanks and your solution works. But i would like to ask why this works, but swapping the `var` line and the `return` line wouldn't work? Thanks!

Comment: @midnite If you swapped `var` and `return` then the variable wouldn't be assigned before it returned the inner function.

Answer (score 64):

This describes the common mistake with using closures in JavaScript.

### A function defines a new environment

Consider:

```
function makeCounter()
{
  var obj = {counter: 0};
  return {
    inc: function(){obj.counter ++;},
    get: function(){return obj.counter;}
  };
}

counter1 = makeCounter();
counter2 = makeCounter();

counter1.inc();

alert(counter1.get()); // returns 1
alert(counter2.get()); // returns 0
```

For each time `makeCounter` is invoked, `{counter: 0}` results in a new object being created. Also, a new copy of `obj` 
is created as well to reference the new object. Thus, `counter1` and `counter2` are independent of each other.

### Closures in loops

Using a closure in a loop is tricky.

Consider:

```
var counters = [];

function makeCounters(num)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    var obj = {counter: 0};
    counters[i] = {
      inc: function(){obj.counter++;},
      get: function(){return obj.counter;}
    }; 
  }
}

makeCounters(2);

counters[0].inc();

alert(counters[0].get()); // returns 1
alert(counters[1].get()); // returns 1
```

Notice that `counters[0]` and `counters[1]` are *not* independent. In fact, they operate on the same `obj`!

This is because there is only one copy of `obj` shared across all iterations of the loop, perhaps for performance reasons.
Even though `{counter: 0}` creates a new object in each iteration, the same copy of `obj` will just get updated with a
reference to the newest object.

Solution is to use another helper function:

```
function makeHelper(obj)
{
  return {
    inc: function(){obj.counter++;},
    get: function(){return obj.counter;}
  }; 
}

function makeCounters(num)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    var obj = {counter: 0};
    counters[i] = makeHelper(obj);
  }
}
```

This works because local variables in the function scope directly, as well as function argument variables, are allocated 
new copies upon entry.

Comment: Small clarification: In the first example of Closures in loops, counters[0] and counters[1] are not independent not because of performance reasons. The reason is that   `var obj = {counter: 0};` is evaluated before any code is executed as stated in: [MDN var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var): 
**var declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed.**

Answer (score 53):

The most simple solution would be,

Instead of using:

```
var funcs = [];
for(var i =0; i<3; i++){
    funcs[i] = function(){
        alert(i);
    }
}

for(var j =0; j<3; j++){
    funcs[j]();
}
```

which alerts "2", for 3 times. This is because anonymous functions created in for loop, shares same closure, and in that closure, the value of `i` is the same. Use this to prevent shared closure:

```
var funcs = [];
for(var new_i =0; new_i<3; new_i++){
    (function(i){
        funcs[i] = function(){
            alert(i);
        }
    })(new_i);
}

for(var j =0; j<3; j++){
    funcs[j]();
}
```

The idea behind this is, encapsulating the entire body of the for loop with an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) and passing `new_i` as a parameter and capturing it as `i`. Since the anonymous function is executed immediately, the `i` value is different for each function defined inside the anonymous function.

This solution seems to fit any such problem since it will require minimal changes to the original code suffering from this issue. In fact, this is by design, it should not be an issue at all!

Comment: Read something similar in a book once. I prefer this, too, since you don't have to touch your existing code (as much) and it becomes obvious why you did it, once you've learned the self-calling function pattern: to trap that variable in the newly created scope.

Comment: @DanMan Thanks. Self calling anonymous functions are very good way to deal javascript's lack of block level variable scope.

Comment: Self-calling, or self-invoking is not the appropriate term for this technique, **IIFE** (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) is more accurately. Ref: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 35):

Here's a simple solution that uses `forEach` (works back to IE9):

```js
var funcs = [];
[0,1,2].forEach(function(i) {          // let's create 3 functions
    funcs[i] = function() {            // and store them in funcs
        console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
    };
})
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();                        // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

Prints:

> ```
> My value: 0
> My value: 1
> My value: 2
> ```

Answer (score 34):

### try this shorter one

- no array
- no extra for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    createfunc(i)();
}

function createfunc(i) {
    return function(){console.log("My value: " + i);};
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7P6EN/

Comment: Your solution seems to output correct but it unneccessarily uses functions, why not just console.log the output? The original question is about creation of anonymous functions that has same closure. The problem was, since they have a single closure, the value of i is same for each of them. I hope you got it.

Answer (score 31):

The main issue with the code shown by the OP is that `i` is never read until the second loop. To demonstrate, imagine seeing an error inside of the code

```
funcs[i] = function() {            // and store them in funcs
    throw new Error("test");
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
};
```

The error actually does not occur until `funcs[someIndex]` is executed `()`. Using this same logic, it should be apparent that the value of `i` is also not collected until this point either. Once the original loop finishes, `i++` brings `i` to the value of `3` which results in the condition `i < 3` failing and the loop ending. At this point, `i` is `3` and so when `funcs[someIndex]()` is used, and `i` is evaluated, it is 3 - every time.

To get past this, you must evaluate `i` as it is encountered. Note that this has already happened in the form of `funcs[i]` (where there are 3 unique indexes). There are several ways to capture this value. One is to pass it in as a parameter to a function which is shown in several ways already here.

Another option is to construct a function object which will be able to close over the variable. That can be accomplished thusly

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/QcUjH/)***

```
funcs[i] = new function() {   
    var closedVariable = i;
    return function(){
        console.log("My value: " + closedVariable); 
    };
};
```

Answer (score 25):

JavaScript functions "close over" the scope they have access to upon declaration, and retain access to that scope even as variables in that scope change.

```js
var funcs = []

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  funcs[i] = function () {
    console.log(i)
  }
}

for (var k = 0; k < 3; k += 1) {
  funcs[k]()
}
```

Each function in the array above closes over the global scope (global, simply because that happens to be the scope they're declared in).

Later those functions are invoked logging the most current value of `i` in the global scope. That's the magic, and frustration, of closure.

**"JavaScript Functions close over the scope they are declared in, and retain access to that scope even as variable values inside of that scope change."**

Using `let` instead of `var` solves this by creating a new scope each time the `for` loop runs, creating a separated scope for each function to close over. Various other techniques do the same thing with extra functions.

```js
var funcs = []

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  funcs[i] = function () {
    console.log(i)
  }
}

for (var k = 0; k < 3; k += 1) {
  funcs[k]()
}
```

(`let` makes variables block scoped. Blocks are denoted by curly braces, but in the case of the for loop the initialization variable, `i` in our case, is considered to be declared in the braces.)

Comment: I struggled to understand this concept until I read this answer. It touches on a really important point – the value of `i` is being set to the global scope. When the `for` loop finishes running, the global value of `i` is now 3. Therefore, whenever that function is invoked in the array (using, say `funcs[j]`), the `i` in that function is referencing the global `i` variable (which is 3).

Answer (score 16):

After reading through various solutions, I'd like to add that the reason those solutions work is to rely on the concept of **scope chain**. It's the way JavaScript resolve a variable during execution.

- Each function definition forms a scope consisting of all the local 
  variables declared by `var` and its `arguments`.
- If we have inner function defined inside another (outer) function, this 
  forms a chain, and will be used during execution
- When a function gets executed, the runtime evaluates variables by searching the **scope chain**. If a variable can be found in a certain point of the chain it will stop searching and use it, otherwise it continues until the global scope reached which belongs to `window`.

In the initial code:

```
funcs = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {         
  funcs[i] = function inner() {        // function inner's scope contains nothing
    console.log("My value: " + i);    
  };
}
console.log(window.i)                  // test value 'i', print 3
```

When `funcs` gets executed, the scope chain will be `function inner -> global`. Since the variable `i` cannot be found in `function inner` (neither declared using `var` nor passed as arguments), it continues to search, until the value of `i` is eventually found in the global scope which is `window.i`.

By wrapping it in an outer function either explicitly define a helper function like [harto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506) did or use an anonymous function like [Bjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750495) did:

```
funcs = {};
function outer(i) {              // function outer's scope contains 'i'
  return function inner() {      // function inner, closure created
   console.log("My value: " + i);
  };
}
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i] = outer(i);
}
console.log(window.i)          // print 3 still
```

When `funcs` gets executed, now the scope chain will be `function inner -> function outer`. This time `i` can be found in the outer function's scope which is executed 3 times in the for loop, each time has value `i` bound correctly. It won't use the value of `window.i` when inner executed.

More detail can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)
It includes the common mistake in creating closure in the loop as what we have here, as well as why we need closure and the performance consideration.

Comment: We rarely write this code sample in real, but I think it serves a good example to understand the fundamental. Once we have the scope in mind and how they chained together, it's more clear to see why other 'modern' ways like `Array.prototype.forEach(function callback(el) {})` naturally works: The callback that's passed in naturally forms the wrapping scope with el correctly bound in each iteration of `forEach`. So every inner function defined in callback will be able to use the right `el` value

Answer (score 15):

With new features of ES6 block level scoping is managed:

```
var funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {          // let's create 3 functions
    funcs[i] = function() {            // and store them in funcs
        console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
    };
}
for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();                        // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

The code in OP's question is replaced with **[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)** instead of **`var`**.

Comment: `const` provides the same result, and should be used when the value of a variable will not change. However, the use of `const` inside the initializer of the for loop is implemented incorrectly in Firefox and has yet to be fixed. Instead of being declared inside the block, it is declared outside the block, which results in a redeclaration to the variable, which in turn results in an error. The use of `let` inside the initializer is implemented correctly in Firefox, so no need to worry there.

Answer (score 12):

> We will check , what actually happens when you declare `var` and `let`
> one by one.

### **Case1** : **using `var`**

```
<script>
   var funcs = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     funcs[i] = function () {
        debugger;
        console.log("My value: " + i);
     };
   }
   console.log(funcs);
</script>
```

Now open your **chrome console window** by pressing **F12** and refresh the page.
Expend every 3 functions inside the array.You will see an property called `[[Scopes]]`.Expand that one. You will see one
array object called `"Global"`,expand that one. You will find a property `'i'` declared into the object which having value 3.

[image]

[image]

**Conclusion:**

1. When you declare a variable using `'var'` outside a function ,it becomes global variable(you can check by typing `i` or
   `window.i` in console window.It will return 3).
2. The anonymous function you declared will not call and check the value inside the function unless you invoke the
   functions.
3. When you invoke the function , `console.log("My value: " + i)` takes the value from its `Global` object and display the
   result.

### **CASE2 : using let**

Now replace the `'var'` with `'let'`

```
<script>
    var funcs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        funcs[i] = function () {
           debugger;
           console.log("My value: " + i);
        };
    }
    console.log(funcs);
</script>
```

Do the same thing, Go to the scopes . Now you will see two objects `"Block"` and `"Global"`. Now expand `Block` object , you
will see 'i' is defined there , and the strange thing is that , for every functions , the value if `i` is different (0 , 1, 2).

[image]

**Conclusion:**

When you declare variable using `'let'` even outside the function but inside the loop , this variable will not be a Global
variable , it will become a `Block` level variable which is only available for the same function only.That is the reason , we
are getting value of `i` different for each function when we invoke the functions.

For more detail about how closer works , please go through the awesome video tutorial https://youtu.be/71AtaJpJHw0

Answer (score 11):

I'm surprised no one yet has suggested using the `forEach` function to better avoid (re)using local variables. In fact, I'm not using `for(var i ...)` at all anymore for this reason.

```
[0,2,3].forEach(function(i){ console.log('My value:', i); });
// My value: 0
// My value: 2
// My value: 3
```

// edited to use `forEach` instead of map.

Comment: `.forEach()` is a much better option if you're not actually mapping anything, and Daryl suggested that 7 months before you posted, so there's nothing to be surprised about.

Comment: This question is not about loop over an array

Comment: Well, he wants to create an array of functions, this example shows how to do that without involving a global variable.

Answer (score 10):

The reason your original example did not work is that all the closures you created in the loop referenced the same frame. In effect, having 3 methods on one object with only a single `i` variable. They all printed out the same value.

Answer (score 10):

This question really shows the history of JavaScript! Now we can avoid block scoping with arrow functions and handle loops directly from DOM nodes using Object methods.

```js
const funcs = [1, 2, 3].map(i => () => console.log(i));
funcs.map(fn => fn())
```

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
Object
  .keys(buttons)
  .map(i => buttons[i].addEventListener('click', () => console.log(i)));
```

```html
<button>0</button><br>
<button>1</button><br>
<button>2</button>
```

Answer (score 9):

First of all, understand what's wrong with this code:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {          // let's create 3 functions
    funcs[i] = function() {            // and store them in funcs
        console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
    };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();                        // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

Here when the `funcs[]` array is being initialized, `i` is being incremented, the `funcs` array is initialized and the size of `func` array becomes 3,  so `i = 3,`. 
Now when the `funcs[j]()` is called, it is again using the variable `i`, which has already been incremented to 3.

Now to solve this, we have many options. Below are two of them:

1. We can initialize `i` with `let` or initialize a new variable `index` with `let` and make it equal to `i`. So when the call is being made, `index` will be used and its scope will end after initialization. And for calling, `index` will be initialized again:

   ```
   var funcs = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {          
       let index = i;
       funcs[i] = function() {            
           console.log("My value: " + index); 
       };
   }
   for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
       funcs[j]();                        
   }
   ```
2. Other Option can be to introduce a `tempFunc` which returns the actual function:

   ```
   var funcs = [];
   function tempFunc(i){
       return function(){
           console.log("My value: " + i);
       };
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {  
       funcs[i] = tempFunc(i);                                     
   }
   for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
       funcs[j]();                        
   }
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Use [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) structure, this would reduce your extra for loop. You can do it in a single for loop:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {     
  (funcs[i] = function() {         
    console.log("My value: " + i); 
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Till ES5, This problem can only be solved using **closure**.

But now in ES6, we have block level scope variables. Changing **var** to **let** in first **for loop** will solve the problem.

```js
var funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're having this sort of problem with a `while` loop, rather than a `for` loop, for example:

```js
var i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, i * 1000);
  i++;
}
```

The technique to close over the current value is a bit different. Declare a block-scoped variable with `const` inside the `while` block, and assign the current `i` to it. Then, wherever the variable is being used asynchronously, replace `i` with the new block-scoped variable:

```js
var i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  const thisIterationI = i;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(thisIterationI);
  }, i * 1000);
  i++;
}
```

For older browsers that don't support block-scoped variables, you can use an IIFE called with `i`:

```js
var i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  (function(innerI) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(innerI);
    }, innerI * 1000);
  })(i);
  i++;
}
```

If the asynchronous action to be invoked happens to be `setTimeout` like the above, you can also call `setTimeout` with a *third* parameter to indicate the argument to call the passed function with:

```js
var i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  setTimeout(
    (thisIterationI) => { // Callback
      console.log(thisIterationI);
    },
    i * 1000, // Delay
    i // Gets passed to the callback; becomes thisIterationI
  );
  i++;
}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the variable can also be declared using `let` instead of `const`. Both allow for block-scoped variables.

Comment: The IIFE  is what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

You could use a declarative module for lists of data such as [query-js](https://github.com/runefs/query-js)(*). In these situations I personally find a declarative approach less surprising

```
var funcs = Query.range(0,3).each(function(i){
     return  function() {
        console.log("My value: " + i);
    };
});
```

You could then use your second loop and get the expected result or you could do

```
funcs.iterate(function(f){ f(); });
```

(*) I'm the author of query-js and therefor biased towards using it, so don't take my words as a recommendation for said library only for the declarative approach :)

Comment: I would love an explanation of the down vote. The code solves the problem at hand. It would be valuable to know how to potentially improve the code

Comment: What is `Query.range(0,3)`? This is not part of the tags for this question. Besides, if you use a third party library, you can provide the link of the documentation.

Comment: @jherax those are or course obvious improvements. Thanks for the comment. I could have sworn that there was already a link. With out that the post was pretty pointless I guess :). My initial idea of keeping it out was because I wasn't trying to push the use of my own library but more the declarative idea. However in hinsight I fully agree that the link should be there

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use `forEach` function, which has its own closure with creating a pseudo range:

```
var funcs = [];

new Array(3).fill(0).forEach(function (_, i) { // creating a range
    funcs[i] = function() {            
        // now i is safely incapsulated 
        console.log("My value: " + i);
    };
});

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j](); // 0, 1, 2
}
```

That looks uglier than ranges in other languages, but IMHO less monstrous than other solutions.

Comment: Prefer it to what? This seems to be a comment in reply to some other answer. It doesn't address the actual question at all (since you aren't assigning a function, to be called later, anywhere).

Comment: It's related exactly to the mentioned issue: how to iterate safely without closure problems

Comment: Now it doesn't seem significantly different from the accepted answer.

Comment: No. In the accepted answer it is suggested to use "some array", but we deal with a range in the answer, it's absolutely different things, which unfortunately don't have a good solution in js, so my answer is trying to solve the issue in a good and practice way

Comment: @Quentin I would recommend to investigate solution before minusing

Answer (score 4):

And yet another solution: instead of creating another loop, just bind the `this` to the return function.

```js
var funcs = [];

function createFunc(i) {
  return function() {
    console.log('My value: ' + i); //log value of i.
  }.call(this);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {  //5 functions
  funcs[i] = createFunc(i);     // call createFunc() i=5 times
}
```

By binding ***this***, solves the problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use let(blocked-scope) instead of var.

```js
var funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      
  funcs[i] = function() {          
    console.log("My value: " + i); 
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work, because what it does is:

```
Create variable `funcs` and assign it an empty array;  
Loop from 0 up until it is less than 3 and assign it to variable `i`;
    Push to variable `funcs` next function:  
        // Only push (save), but don't execute
        **Write to console current value of variable `i`;**

// First loop has ended, i = 3;

Loop from 0 up until it is less than 3 and assign it to variable `j`;
    Call `j`-th function from variable `funcs`:  
        **Write to console current value of variable `i`;**  
        // Ask yourself NOW! What is the value of i?
```

Now the question is, what is the value of variable `i` when the function is called? Because the first loop is created with the condition of `i < 3`, it stops immediately when the condition is false, so it is `i = 3`.

You need to understand that, in time when your functions are created, none of their code is executed, it is only saved for later. And so when they are called later, the interpreter executes them and asks: "What is the current value of `i`?"

So, your goal is to first save the value of `i` to function and only after that save the function to `funcs`. This could be done for example this way:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {          // let's create 3 functions
    funcs[i] = function(x) {            // and store them in funcs
        console.log("My value: " + x); // each should log its value.
    }.bind(null, i);
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();                        // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

This way, each function will have it's own variable `x` and we set this `x` to the value of `i` in each iteration.

This is only one of the multiple ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function(param) {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + param); // each should log its value.
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j](j);                      // and now let's run each one to see with j
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem often encountered with asynchronous code, the variable `i` is mutable and at the time at which the function call is made the code using `i` will be executed and `i` will have mutated to its last value, thus meaning all functions created within the loop will create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and `i` will be equal to 3 (the upper bound + 1 of the `for` loop.

A workaround to this, is to create a function that will hold the value of `i` for each iteration and force a copy `i` (as it is a primitive, think of it as a snapshot if it helps you).

Answer (score 2):

Many solutions seem correct but they don't mention it's called [`Currying`](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/) which is a functional programming design pattern for situations like here. 3-10 times faster than bind depending on the browser.

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = curryShowValue(i);
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      // and now let's run each one to see
}

function curryShowValue(i) {
  return function showValue() {
    console.log("My value: " + i);
  }
}
```

See [the performance gain in different browsers](https://jsperf.com/bind-vs-curry).

Comment: @TinyGiant The example with function being returned is still currying optimised for performance. I wouldn't jump on arrow functions bandwagon like all the JavaScript bloggers. They look cool and clean but promote writing functions inline instead of using predefined functions. This can be a non-obvious trap in hot places. Another problem is that they are not just syntactic sugar because they are executing unnecessary bindings thus creating wrapping closures.

Comment: **Warning to future readers:** This answer inaccurately applies the term _Currying_. [_"Currying is when you break down a function that takes multiple arguments into a series of functions that take part of the arguments."_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321/4639281). This code does nothing of the sort. All you've done here is take the code from the accepted answer, move some things around, change the style and naming a bit, then call it currying, which it categorically is not.

Answer (score 2):

**COUNTER BEING A PRIMITIVE**

Let's define callback functions as follows:

```
// ****************************
// COUNTER BEING A PRIMITIVE
// ****************************
function test1() {
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }
}
test1();
// 2
// 2
```

After timeout completes it will print 2 for both. This is because the callback function accesses the value based on the [lexical scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1047454/7032856), where it was function was defined.

To pass and preserve the value while callback was defined, we can create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), to preserve the value before the callback is invoked. This can be done as follows:

```
function test2() {
    function sendRequest(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sendRequest(i);
    }
}
test2();
// 1
// 2
```

Now what's special about this is "The primitives are passed by value and copied. Thus when the closure is defined, they keep the value from the previous loop."

**COUNTER BEING AN OBJECT**

Since closures have access to parent function variables via reference, this approach would differ from that for primitives.

```
// ****************************
// COUNTER BEING AN OBJECT
// ****************************
function test3() {
    var index = { i: 0 };
    for (index.i=0; index.i<2; index.i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('test3: ' + index.i);
        });
    }
}
test3();
// 2
// 2
```

So, even if a closure is created for the variable being passed as an object, the value of the loop index will not be preserved. This is to show that the values of an object are not copied whereas they are accessed via reference.

```
function test4() {
    var index = { i: 0 };
    function sendRequest(index, i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('index: ' + index);
            console.log('i: ' + i);
            console.log(index[i]);
        });
    }

    for (index.i=0; index.i<2; index.i++) {
        sendRequest(index, index.i);
    }
}
test4();
// index: { i: 2}
// 0
// undefined

// index: { i: 2}
// 1
// undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the var keyword to let.

var is function scoped.

let is block scoped.

When you start you code the for loop will iterate and assign the value of i to 3, which will remain 3 throughout your code. I suggest you to read more about scopes in node (let,var,const and others)

```
funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] =async function() {          // and store them in funcs
    await console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just replaced `var` with `let`

```js
var funcs = []
// change `var` to `let`
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i] = function(){
    console.log("My value:", i); //change to the copy
  }
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take advantage of [`new Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). Thus `i` stops to be a variable of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and becomes just a part of the text:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var functionBody = 'console.log("My value: ' + i + '");';
    funcs[i] = new Function(functionBody);
}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    funcs[j]();
}
```

Comment: This is slow, potentially insecure, and doesn't work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is old and answered,  I have yet another fairly interesting solution:

```
var funcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {     
  funcs[i] = function() {          
    console.log("My value: " + i); 
 };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i]();
}
```

The change is so small it's almost difficult to see what I did. I switched the second iterator from a j to an i. This somehow refreshes the state of i in time to give you the desired result. I did this by accident but it makes sense considering previous answers.

I wrote this up to point out this small, yet very important difference. Hope that helps to clear up some confusion for other learners like me.

Note: I am not sharing this because I think it's the right answer. This is a flakey solution that probably will break under certain circumstances. Actually, I'm quite amazed that it really works.

Comment: It's only working because in the second loop, you're overwriting the same `i` as is referenced in the function. Just consider that in this whole snippet, there is only one `i` variable. It is equivalent to:
`i = 0; funcs[0](); i = 1; funcs[1](); ..`

Comment: right, which makes sense considering the other answers about scoping, but still is sort of counterintuitive

Comment: You are overwriting the value `i` from `3` to `0,1,2,3` and calling using that values immediately @nickf does that mean `j=0` goin to be `funcs[0]` too

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you don't use ES6;
You can use IIFEs:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {      
    funcs[i] = (function(x) {
      console.log("My value: " + i)
     })(i);
   }
```

But it will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I read through all of the answers. Even though there is a good explanation here - I just could not get this to work. So I went looking on the internet. The person at https://dzone.com/articles/why-does-javascript-loop-only-use-last-value had an answer which is not presented here. So I thought I'd post a short example. This made a lot more sense to me.

The long and short of it is that the LET command is nice but is only now being used. HOWEVER, the LET command is really just a TRY-CATCH combo. This works all the way back to IE3 (I believe). Using the TRY-CATCH combo - life is simple and good. Probably why the EMCScript people decided to use it. It also does not need a setTimeout() function. So no time is lost. Basically, you need one TRY-CATCH combo per FOR loop. Here is an example:

```
    for( var i in myArray ){
       try{ throw i }
       catch(ii){
// Do whatever it is you want to do with ii
          }
       }
```

If you have more than one FOR loop, you just put a TRY-CATCH combo for each one. Also, personally, I always use the double letter of whatever FOR variable I am using. So "ii" for "i" and so on. I am using this technique in a routine to send mouseover commands to a different routine.

Answer (score 0):

This proves how ugly javascript is with regard to how 'closure' and 'non-closure' works.

In the case of:

```
var funcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
}
```

funcs[i] is a global function, and 'console.log("My value: " + i);' is printing global variable i

In the case of

```
var funcs = [];

function createfunc(i) {
    return function() { console.log("My value: " + i); };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] = createfunc(i);
}
```

because of this twisted closure design of javascript, 'console.log("My value: " + i);' is printing the i from outer function 'createfunc(i)'

all because javascript can not design something decent like the 'static' variable inside a function like what C programming language is doing!

Answer (score 0):

```
  asyncIterable = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

  (async function() {
       for await (let num of asyncIterable) {
         console.log(num);
       }
    })();
```

Comment: It's always better to add some explanation to the code so that users will understand it better. Try to explain why your way is better than the ones from the other answers :)

Comment: Thanks @FedericoGrandi, after two pages of examples I thought that will not be required.

Answer (score -1):

Already many valid answers to this question. Not many using a functional approach though. Here is an alternative solution using the `forEach` method, which works well with callbacks and closures:

```
let arr = [1,2,3];

let myFunc = (val, index) => { 
    console.log('val: '+val+'\nindex: '+index);
};

arr.forEach(myFunc);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply call each function inside the first (and only) loop just after they were created, such as:

```
 var funcs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // let's create 3 functions
    funcs[i] = function() {
    // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
    };
    funcs[i]();// and now let's run each one to see
    }
```

Comment: Because it was just an example of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

With the support of `ES6`, the best way to this is to use `let` and `const` keywords for this exact circumstance. So `var` variable get `hoisted` and with the end of loop the value of `i` gets updated for all the `closures`..., we can just use `let` to set a loop scope variable like this:

```
var funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {          
    funcs[i] = function() {            
      console.log("My value: " + i); 
    };
}
```