# passing arguments to addeventlistener in titanium

Tags: titanium

I require to pass arguments to callback handler of addEventListener. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function), but it doesn't work in **for** loop. 
Here is my code:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    //configuration here.
});
for(var i=0,ilen=response.length; i<ilen; i++){
    var thisObj = response[i];
    var btnCareer = Ti.UI.createButton({
        //configuration here
    });

    var careerID = thisObj.CareerID;
    btnCareer.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
                                                            bh.logic.career.CareerClick(careerID);
                                    });
    view.add(btnCareer);
}
```

What i get is the latest value.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/84241/dynamically-assign-listener-to-button). Basically, i should remember that javascript is loosely coupled language.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what response[] contains and if careerID is intended to be linear, etc, the purpose of the following **code** is to suggest adding the careerID as an actual **id** property of the button; something which can be referenced.

I also do not know what Platform you are developing for ;-) so, give the following a whirl and if all else fails, check out:

[The Button API by clicking here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.1/Titanium.UI.Button-object.html)

HTH!!

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    //configure the view here.
});

for(var i=0,ilen=response.length; i<ilen; i++){
    var thisObj = response[i];
    var careerID = thisObj.CareerID;
    var btnCareer = Ti.UI.createButton({
        //configuration here
        id:careerID // THIS GIVES THIS BUTTON AN ID TO MAP BY EVENT LISTENER ONCLICK
    });
    btnCareer.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if ( e.source.id !== null ) {  // Be good and check for null values
            var careerIDValue = e.source.id;
            /* e is this function, source looks at id value for the button you just
             * created as it attaches the eventListener to the most current button
             * object and keeps the button unique because you've given it an id: blah
             * value that can be sussed out
             */ 
            bh.logic.career.CareerClick(careerIDValue);
        } else {
            alert('NULL ID FOUND!  ARGH! ' + e.source.id);
        }
    });
    view.add(btnCareer);
}
```

Comment: Actually, i had to pass more than one variable value to the click event, so i rather would like to go with currently marked answer.