# Stop listening to postMessage message event

Tags: html, postmessage

I can not seem to have the receiver event listener removed. Given the code below the console will continue printing "*hi*" endlessly.

**Receiver**:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
       console.log('hi');
       window.removeEventListener("message", function(e){}, false)
}, false);
```

**Sender** :

```
var emiter = setInterval(function(){
            console.log('sending message');
            window.parent.postMessage( messageData, "*" );
        }, 1000);
```

Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe in order to remove the listener you have to have a reference to the same function so like this:

```
var f = function(e){
  console.log('hi');
  window.removeEventListener("message", f, false);
}
window.addEventListener("message", f);
```

So the reason your's doesn't work is because it doesn't have a reference to that function as a listener.

Comment: Yea right too much jquery i forgot about that, thanks.. though in that case how do can i pass parameter to my callback, other than the event object?

Comment: I don't believe you can, you just need to get values after.

Comment: this may help you in some way but I still don't think it's entirely possible to add parameters to pass to the function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function