# How to pass some parameters to function called in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)

How can I pass some argument (in this case an integer) to a function through `addEventListener` on a `click` event?

I have two buttons; if I press the right one I want to do some stuff, if I press the left one then I'd like it to do something else.

Here's the code:

```
document.getElementById('date_right').addEventListener( 'click', switch_date(1), false );
document.getElementById('date_left').addEventListener( 'click', switch_date(-1), false );
  function switch_date( k )
  {
    if(k==1)
    {
      //do stuff
    }
  else
  {
    //another stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't. Use anonymous functions:

```
document.getElementById('date_right').addEventListener('click', function () {
    switch_date(1);
}, false);
document.getElementById('date_left').addEventListener('click', function () {
    switch_date(-1);
}, false);
```

Or use named functions which do not take arguments:

```
function onRightDateClick() {
    switch_date(1);
}

function onLeftDateClick() {
    switch_date(-1);
}

document.getElementById('date_right').addEventListener('click', onRightDateClick, false);
document.getElementById('date_left').addEventListener('click', onLeftDateClick, false);
```

Comment: And how to remove this eventListener ? if there is anonymous function.

Comment: document.getElementById("myDIV").removeEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);