# JS: input's .value returns an empty string (when not empty)

Tags: javascript, textinput

I've been trying to get the value from a text input, but for some reason, it's not working.

Essentially, I have a text input. The user types inside of the input, and I'd expect the `.value` property to change (which chrome says it does), but when I click to save it, and read my JSON output, it returns as a blank string.

Here's the HTML for this bit:

```
<input id="eventName" name="efrm" type="text" value="" />
<button type="button" id="okEvent">Save Event</button>
```

Here's the JS that you'll need to see:

```
document.querySelector("#okEvent").addEventListener("mousedown", applyEvent(event), false);

function applyEvent(event) {
    var eventName = document.querySelector("#eventName").value;

    event.data = {
        name: eventName,
        img: null,
        type: 1,
        fov: 0,
        orientation: 1,
        trigger: 1
    };
}
```

The JSON output says that the name property of the event.data object is an empty string, though. I'm really not understanding what's going on here.

Comment: At least in ie, event is a global variable.  By using event in your applyEvent function, you are masking over the global variable.  Probably should change the variable name.

Comment: See [How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/256754/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `applyEvent` **immediately** and pass the **return value** to `addEventListener` (which is `undefined`). Since the input element doesn't have a value yet at that moment, `.value` will return an empty string.

Pass a function instead:

```
....addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    applyEvent(event);
}, false);
```

(I don't know where `event` is coming from in your code, but I assume it is a custom object, *not* the actual event object).

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you very much. Stack overflow said I have to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer, but I will when the time comes. Thanks!