# Redefining nested function's variable from each call to parent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, nested

I've got a nested function inside another JavaScript function; the nested function accepts a variable that is passed to the parent. The first time I call the parent, all variables are set correctly. However any subsequent times that I call the parent, the nested function doesn't apply the new variable that was passed to the parent (instead it persists the variable from the first call).

For example:

```
myFunc: function(path, points) {
   var onDrag      = function(e) {

       // This is the variable I want redefined each time I 
       // call myFunc with new points
       console.log('points: ', points);

    },
    onDragStart   = function(e) {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDrag);
    };

    this.el.addEventListener('mousedown', onDragStart);

    return this;
}
```

The above is a stripped-down version of my method. I call `myFunc` when I create my element, and as you can see `onDrag` gets called on `mousedown` on the element. But, I also call `myFunc` directly at several points later in the script, passing it new variables for path and points, expecting `onDrag`'s references to these variables to update.

However, this isn't happening, instead onDrag is persisting the points variable from the first time I called it.

**How can I have my nested function update it's variables each time I call its parent?**

What I've tried:

I've tried passing points as an argument to the `onDrag`, like this:

`onDrag = function(e, points) { }`

I've tried redefining a variable inside the onDrag scope, like this:

`onDrag = function(e) { var pts = points; }`

I've tried not defining the function in a variable, like this:

`function onDrag(e) { }`

But none of these things has worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the "myFunc" again it will again attach add new eventListner on window object.
You need to first remove previously attached event from window.

> window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDrag, false);

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the arguments to onDrag at the time that you invoke it.

```
myFunc: function(path, points) {
   var onDrag      =  function(e, points) {

        // This is the variable I want redefined each time I 
        // call myFunc with new points
        console.log('points: ', points);


    },

    onDragStart   = function(e, points) {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDrag(e, points));
    };

    this.el.addEventListener('mousedown', onDragStart(e, points));

    return this;
}
```

Comment: To pass arguments, I've got to write it like this:

 window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
   onDrag(e, points);
 });

Unfortunately that means I wouldn't be able to unbind the event later:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/256763/740836