# Apply a JavaScript handler to all occurrences of a certain HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to setup an event handler for all occurrences of a certain HTML tag, for example **`onclick()=my_f()`** event in tag `<p>` in HTML file like this :

```
<body>
<p id="1"></p>
<p id="2"></p>
<p id="3"></p>
</body>
```

the result would be that `my_f()` is the handler for all `<p>` .
the catch is that I don't want to write : `<p id="1" onclick()="my_f()">` for every `<p>`, so I tried doing so in JavaScript, like this:
JSutil.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
   init();
   alert("Hello!");
}
 
function init() {

    for (var i = document.getElementsByTagName("P").length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        alert("i "+i);
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover", readenter(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].id));
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("onmouseout", readleave(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].id));
    };
}

function readenter(id) {
    alert("readenter , id "+id);
}
function readleave(id) {
    alert("readleave , id "+id);
}
```

and in the HTML file I did :

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JSutil.js"></script>
</head>
```

The problem is that the `readenter()` and `readleave()` gets called at the start of the page (onload), and when I move in/out over the paragraphs (`<P>`) nothing happens.
The ids that are printed in alert (in `readenter()` and `readleave()`) are correct and belongs to the `<p>` in my HTML.
I tried also doing:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].onmouseover = readenter(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].id);
```

same result.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you called the function, instead of binding the event to it.
Instead of

```
  document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover", 
      readenter(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].id));
```

Write

```
  document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover", readenter);
```

And "readenter" will be called.

However your code is very verbose for lack of a better term, and it may break down in certain browsers. Try using jQuery for example. Using jQuery you would write:

```
$("p").mouseover(readenter).mouseleave(readleave)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to attach `function` while adding `eventlistener` and not call it. So changes to be done in `for-loop` is as below:

```
for (var i = document.getElementsByTagName("P").length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        alert("i "+i);
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover", readenter);
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("onmouseout", readleave);
};
```

Or if at all you want to pass a parameter then create an `anonymous function` while adding `eventlistener` as below:

```
for (var i = document.getElementsByTagName("P").length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        alert("i "+i);
        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("mouseover", 
           function(){
               readenter(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].id)
           }
        );

        document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].addEventListener("onmouseout",
            function(){
               readleave(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].id);
            }
        )
};
```

You can find still more good solutions from **[this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)**