# Newly created button (by createElement("Button")) activates itself. How to stop that?

Tags: javascript, html

In `hmtl` file I have a simple button

```
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="create_button()">Create button</button>
</body>
```

and in `js` file I have two functions

```
function create_button() {
    var new_button = document.createElement("Button");
    new_button.innerHTML = "Pop the alert";
    new_button.type = "button";
    new_button.onClick = my_function();
    document.body.appendChild(new_button);
};
function my_function() {
    alert("Not so fast");
};
```

Obviously it should work in following manner:

- Click **Create button** -> **Pop the alert** button appears
- Click **Pop an alert** -> "Not so fast" alert appers

However after I click **Create button**, the alert appears. I guess that **Pop an alert** button activates itsef, but I don't know how to prevent it from doing so.

---

Edit. I actually have a problem in which `my_function` depends on some parameters.
So lets say we have following situation:

```
function my_function(x) {
    alert("I like " + x);
};
```

and I want to create button which does `my_function("Stack Overflow")`.

Based on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function) discussion I used

```
new_button.addEventListener('click', function(){my_function("Stack Overflow");});
```

and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `new_button.addEventListener('click',my_function);`. 
So `my_function` would be referenced, but not called imidiatley:

```js
function create_button() {
  var new_button = document.createElement("Button");
  new_button.innerHTML = "Pop the alert";
  new_button.type = "button";
  new_button.addEventListener('click', my_function);
  document.body.appendChild(new_button);
};

function my_function() {
  alert("Not so fast");
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="create_button()">Create button</button>
```

**After the edit**

If your `my_function` have `arguments`, you have to wrap it into `anonymous function`, so it would be:

```
new_button.addEventListener('click',function(){
 my_function(5);
});
```

**Or**

```
new_button.onclick=function(){
           my_function(5);};
```

Comment: It works. But what should I do if my_function have some parameters, like my_function(x)? Cause `addEventListener('click', my_function(5));`does not work.

Comment: then you can wrap it into anonymous function: `.addEventListener('click',function(){
        my_function(5);});`You can also do that with `.onclick`

Comment: Thx. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

As extend to @itsgoingdown answer:

```
function create_button() {
  var new_button = document.createElement("Button");
  new_button.innerHTML = "Pop the alert";
  new_button.type = "button";
  new_button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var x = ' sport'
    my_function(x) 
  });
  document.body.appendChild(new_button);
};

function my_function(x) {
  alert("Not so fast" + x);
};
```