# Passing a variable to an addEventListener function

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am having troubles trying to figure out why this code does not run. I get no error in the console at all.

```
const remove = saClass => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('site-alert')[0].remove();
};

const sitealert = ({message = 'Default message', dismissText = 'Close', className = 'site-alert'}) => {
  render(`<div id="sitealert" class="${className}">${message}<button id='close-message'>${dismissText}</button><div>`);
  document.getElementById('close-message').addEventListener('click', remove(className), false);
};

export const init = (options) => sitealert(options);
```

When i add a parameter  `remove(className)` to the addEventListener the code does not run at all and I get no error in the console.

If I remove the parameter it all works fine.

Am i passing a variable incorrectly?

I should note that I am using babel to convert the code into a UMD format.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: This question has been answered at least a thousand times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a closure to pass in the variable and then return the actual callback:

```
const sitealert = ({message = 'Default message', dismissText = 'Close', className = 'site-alert'}) => {
  render(`<div id="sitealert" class="${className}">${message}<button id='close-message'>${dismissText}</button><div>`);
  document.getElementById('close-message').addEventListener('click', remove(className), false);
};

function remove(yourVar) {
    return function (e) {
        //yourVar is available here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An expression like

```
functionName(expression)
```

is a **call** to the function. What you want is another function. You can do that explicitly:

```
() => remove(className)
```

or with `.bind()`:

```
remove.bind(null, className)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `addEventListener` needs to be a function.

`remove` is a function.

`remove(className)` is the result of calling that function with an argument. Since the function has no `return` statement, that result is `undefined`.

If you want to generate a function that will call `remove` with an argument, use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```
remove.bind(null, className)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fonction with parameters, you should use:

```
.addEventListener('onclick', function() {remove(className)}, true);
```

in order to specify its a function