# JavaScript : How to pass object as argument to addEventListener function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JavaScript code is as follows

```
$.getJSON( "sample_json.json", function( data ) {
  //javascript object
  var someId = data['item'][0]['id'];
  console.log("Outside addEventListener "+someId);

  //create <tr> element
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  //bind click event
  tr.addEventListener("click",function() {
    console.log("inside addEventListener "+someId);
    someFunction(someId);
  },false);       
});

//function
function someFunction(someId){
  console.log("Inside someFunction "+someId);
}
```

Now when I click on `<tr>` element it gives following in output

```
Outside addEventListener 150
Inside addEventListener 1
Inside someFunction 1
```

When I change `someId` as

```
var someId = 150;
```

It works perfectly

```
Outside addEventListener 150
Inside addEventListener 150
Inside someFunction 150
```

What should I change in javascript code to get the actual id from javascript object on click event ?

**Note:** I have already referred the existing question on Stack Overflow.
[How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)
But have not helped much.

**Edit:** Updated javascript code with some jquery functions, which creates `data` javascript object from JSON file.

Comment: No my data object is not modified anywhere.

Comment: This code _should_ work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing object as argument, I would suggest you to use `data-attribute`

```
$.getJSON( "sample_json.json", function( data ) {
  //javascript object
  var someId = data['item'][0]['id'];
  console.log("Outside addEventListener "+someId);

  //create <tr> element
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  tr.setAttribute('data-someId', someId);

  //bind click event
  $('tr').on("click",function() {
    console.log("inside addEventListener "+$(this).data('someId'));
    someFunction($(this).data('someId'));
  },false);       
});

//function
function someFunction(someId){
  console.log("Inside someFunction "+someId);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Pankaj Welcome buddy :). Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are changing someId later in the programme to 1 and that's why it the event handler prints 1 and not 150.
If you create a closure around the event handler function you can bind the someId to the value it had at the time the event handler function was created (150).
You can create a closure like this:

```
tr.addEventListener("click",(function(someId)
{
    return function() {
     console.log("inside addEventListener "+someId);
     someFunction(someId);
    }
})(someId),false);
```