# How can I pass an argument to the callback function of an event listener without losing the "event" property?

Tags: javascript, events, callback

I have no idea of how to do this, I want to pass an argument to the callback function "ctrlDeleteItem":

document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', ctrlDeleteItem);

But if I do that, I lose access to the event property, example:

```
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', ctrlDeleteItem(item));

function ctrlDeleteItem(item, event) {
  return function() {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

How can I still pass the event as a parameter? I can't find how to do it, thanks.

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11986895/598478

Comment: There is some event delegation, so event.target is not the same element that I am selecting with document.querySelector('.container')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is incorrect because it will cause the `ctrlDeleteItem` function to be executed immediately. That can be shown by adding a `console.log("test")` statement to the `ctrlDeleteItem()` function - you'll get the message immediately.

The correct solution is to set up a "wrapper" callback function that will receive the event as usual and then have that wrapper call the actual callback function with whatever arguments are needed. The wrapper can pass the `event` to the actual callback if desired.

```js
const item = 'foo';
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', function(evt){ 
  ctrlDeleteItem(evt, item);
});

function ctrlDeleteItem(evt, item) {
    console.log(evt.type, item);
    console.log(event.target.className);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">container</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `event` as an argument to the *returned* function in `ctrlDeleteItem`, so that it will be used properly as the `event` in the listener:

```
function ctrlDeleteItem(item) {
  return function(event) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

```js
const item = 'foo';
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', ctrlDeleteItem(item));

function ctrlDeleteItem(item) {
  return function(event) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(event.target.className);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">container</div>
```

Comment: This is not correct. See my answer below for why and the correct solution.

Comment: But from his code, it looked like he *did* want to invoke `ctrlDeleteItem` immediately. If you essentially want to pass an additional argument to the listener at the time you add the listener, using a function that returns a function *is* a fine way to accomplish that

Comment: I interpret it as him trying any code that would work. He doesn't state that running `ctrlDeleteItem` immediately is a requirement. He only states that he wants to pass arguments to the callback without losing the event reference. Unless we need dynamic callback construction, this solution becomes an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yeah well, I used a closure there just so both logs executed when the event triggers, and not automatically, I didnt know that there was another way to avoid the invocation of the listener function... thanks to both of you, both answers helped me to learn how this works.