# Angular Renderer2 remove listener leaves EventListeners in memory - memory leak?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, angular6, angular2-directives, angular-renderer2

I have 3 event listeners in directive which i add and remove on button toggle and remove

```
private addListeners() {
    this.mouseLeaveFunc = this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'mouseleave', () => {

    });
    this.mouseEnterFunc = this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'mouseenter', () => {

    });
    this.onClickFunc = this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {

    });
}

 private removeListeners() {
    if (this.mouseLeaveFunc) {
        this.mouseLeaveFunc();
        this.mouseEnterFunc();
        this.onClickFunc();
    }
}
```

After listeners remove Angular is not listening for them any more however comparing mempry dump taken after first click and second click i see that second has 9 listener more (i have 3 directive on the page so 3 el x 3 listeners).

[image]

Any ideas is it memory leak or how to remove them?

Comment: Btw when i am adding and removing event listeners like
this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.onMouseLeave);

and comapring memory dump there are no listeners left. Btw whats an advantage of adding listeners via renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... it seems you're running Angular in dev mode. Your EventListeners may be attached to Angular's `DebugElement`. If you are creating and removing nodes using Renderer2 you might also notice that all your `Detached HTMLElement`s are retained in memory.

Don't worry too much because this all disappears in prod mode.

> Btw whats an advantage of adding listeners via renderer?

It saves you the trouble of manually removing event listeners. If you use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` with pure JavaScript, you will have to name your listener function. It will also be a pain to pass class parameters if you need to perform some data manipulation: [How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)

Renderer's `listen` method supports listening and unlistening to anonymous functions, supports class functions that reference your component class (which `addEventListener` does not support - using `addEventListener`, `this` will point to the target element, not your component class) and easily supports calling listener functions with additional arguments. It's versatile and safe, providing you remember to unlisten.

Additionally, Angular's unlisten mechanic is more reliable than calling `removeEventListener`. `removeEventListener` requires the developer to supply the exact parameters, can easily fail, and doesn't have a return value or notify to tell you whether you've successfully removed something. With Renderer2 you're practically guaranteed that you're removing the right EventListener.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tested it and this is truly dev mode issue and I see your point however about other things with some of your points I dissagree. "this" is fully suported with TypeScript by passing arrow function: this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.onMouseLeave); Removing listener cannot be more reliable in Angular because it is wrapper and failure if more common because as you said it supports passing parameters - with native event listener there is only on param - event so you cannot fail. However i support idea to use framewrok approach rather then pure.

Comment: I was referring to wrapping a class function in an anonymous function to pass parameters. Also I thought that when `this.onMouseLeave` references for example `this.otherClassParam`, the `this` inside `this.onMouseLeave` refers to `this.el.nativeElement`. Guess I was wrong then :)

Comment: hey @Jasmonate, can you provide any source for this "Don't worry too much because this all disappears in prod mode."

Comment: I am also very curious about this. Sadly, this seems to slow down my app a lot in dev.