# How to remove Event listener with currying function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm having a hard time to remove Event listener type currying function.

```
// I register first, at some time I want to remove using freezeHighlight but it doesn't working (without currying function it's working like a charm)
const privateMethods = {
  highlighted (index) {
    return function (event) {
      event.target.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#glow)')

      // need param index later
    }
  }
}

register (node, index) {
      node.addEventListener('mouseover', privateMethods.highlighted(index))
  }

freezeHighlight (node) {
        node.removeEventListener('mouseover', privateMethods.highlighted)
  }
```

Is it possible to remove event listener type currying function or should I procede with a workaround?

Comment: I would think you'd need to capture the curried function reference before registering it, so that you could use that reference later to remove the event listener. You'd need  to set a variable scoped high enough to be accessible to `privateMethods` and your two register functions. Closures around the variable would make this work.

Comment: Sorry can you make a little example so I can see how to do that ?

Comment: `privateMethods.highlighted(index)` this is a method call not an event handler if that's what you want to do, pass an anonymous function then call `privateMethods.highlighted(index)` inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to memoize the handler you create so that you can remove it later.

```
const handlers = {};

const privateMethods = {
  highlighted (index) {
    // return the saved handler if we've been called before
    // or create a new handler, save it, and return it.
    return handlers[index] || (handlers[index] = function (event) {
      event.target.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#glow)')

      // need param index later
    });
  }
}

register (node, index) {
      // add the handler
      node.addEventListener('mouseover', privateMethods.highlighted(index))
}

freezeHighlight (node, index) {
      // will remove the handler
        node.removeEventListener('mouseover', privateMethods.highlighted(index))
}
```

Comment: thank you! that's a smart way of dealing with event listener

Answer (score 1):

```
var listener
register (node, index) {
    listener = privateMethods.highlighted(index)
    node.addEventListener('mouseover', listener)
}

freezeHighlight (node) {
    node.removeEventListener('mouseover', listener)
}
```

You think `privateMethods.highlighted` is the listener. No it's not. The return value of `privateMethods.highlighted(index)` is the listener.