# JavaScript foreach eventlistener ends up with the same count

Tags: javascript, events, count

I have two event listeners and I have a counter. When I click the element, I always get the last number of the counter.

How can I get or pass the correct counter.

```js
let i = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(element => {
 element.addEventListener("click", () => {
   console.log(i);
 })
 i++;
});
```

```html
<div>
Click me
</div>

<div>
Click me too
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known mistake in using *callback in the loop*. If you wish to have the number of the element clicked you need to use *closure*. Something like this.

```js
let i = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(element => {
  ((j) => element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(j);
  }))(i);
  i++;
});
```

```html
<div>
  Click me
</div>

<div>
  Click me too
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for. Thanks! In the meantime I found an alternative solution which is to add params to the event object and then get them later from there, see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11986895/148496 Not sure which way I prefer yet.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is when page loads, two `div` elements are found where `click` events have been attached and in the same time the variable `i` value has been increased two times. At the end on each click, you have logged value `2` into the console.

If you want to increase the number value on each click then you need to move `i++` into the `click` event like the following:

```js
let i = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(element => {
 element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    i++;
    console.log(i);   
 });
});
```

```html
<div>Click me</div>
<div>Click me too</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing `i` in the incorrect location.  It should be in the click callback.

```js
let i = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(element => {
 element.addEventListener("click", () => {
   i++;
   console.log(i);
 })
});
```

```html
<div>
Click me
</div>

<div>
Click me too
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The increment(`i++`) should be inside the event handler:

```js
let i = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(element => {
 element.addEventListener("click", () => {
   console.log(i);
    i++;
 })

});
```

```html
<div>
Click me
</div>

<div>
Click me too
</div>
```