# How can I add a removable event listener to a list of elements, but still pass parameters to the function it calls?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, addeventlistener

I have a list of elements stored in a variable called `elementList`, and want to add an event listener to each of them. So I created the following loop:

```js
for (i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
  elementList[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

The problem? I need to pass on `i` as a parameter to `myFunction`. After doing some research online, I found this solution:

```js
for (i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
  elementList[i].addEventListener('click', (function(i){
    return function(){
      myFunction(i);
    };
  }(i)), false);
}
```

The code works nicely – but there's still a problem. Later on in my code, I need to remove the event listener again, which is done with the `removeEventListener()` method, as I found out after some more research.

But this method requires a named, external function – it doesn't work for anonymous functions. So it would work for my first example above, but not for the second.

So my question is: how do I add an event listener to a list of elements, which allows me to do both of these things:

1. Pass parameters to my function
2. Remove the event listener again, later in the code

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I'm not sure. I know how to pass arguments in an `addEventListener` function, I just don't know how to do it in a way that can be removed again later. Does the question you have provided a link to answer this second point as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a list of functions and use them to remove the listener:

```
let removers = elementList.map((el, idx) => {
  let handler = () => myFunction(idx);
  el.addEventListener('click', handler);
  return () => el.removeEventListener('click', handler);
});

// when you need
//
removers[4]();  // calls removeEventListener
```

Comment: Thanks very much for answering! However, I haven't been able to correctly implement this. If you have time, could you check my edited question above? I've added a code snippet at the end which explains what I mean.

Comment: @Run_Script in which version of ecmascript are you working?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to find that out. Does the code snippet which I added to the question work for you? It doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: @Run_Script git a look to this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/30dx7z5u/

Comment: Thanks very much, I understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the event listener from the button, you'll need to have a reference to the function itself. So before using `addEventListener` store the function in an object or an array, or something where you can look back and find this function. Because `removeEventListener` won't work if you don't give it the exact same function as you used with `addEventListener`.

Down below in the code snippet I've constructed an example of a way to store these event listeners and call it an `EventCollection`. This class functions as a container and holds a list of every event that you want to add. This way you can add or remove all the event listeners you want anytime in your code, without having to do too much work.

```js
class EventCollection {

  /**
   * Create a list to store the entries in.
   */
  constructor() {
    this.entries = [];
    this.isListening = false;
  }

  /**
   * Add an entry to the collection to listen for on an event.
   */
  append(target, type, listener, options = false) {
    if (!(target instanceof EventTarget)) return;
    this.entries.push({ target, type, listener, options });
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Listen for all the entries in the list.
   */
  listen() {
    if (!this.isListening) {
      this.entries.forEach(({ target, type, listener, options }) => {
        target.addEventListener(type, listener, options);
      });
      this.isListening = true;
    }
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Stop listening for all the entries in the list.
   */
  stopListening() {
    this.entries.forEach(({ target, type, listener, options }) => {
      target.removeEventListener(type, listener, options);
    });
    this.isListening = false;
    return this;
  } 

}

// Create a new instance of an EventCollection
var eventCollection = new EventCollection();

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

function myFunction(index) {
  alert(index);
}

// Add all the event listeners to the collection.
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  (function(i){
    eventCollection.append(buttons[i], 'click', function() {
      myFunction(i);
    }, false);
  }(i));
}

// Start listening.
eventCollection.listen();

// After 5 seconds, stop listening.
// The buttons won't work anymore.
setTimeout(function() {
  eventCollection.stopListening();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
```

Building the collection works like this. With the `new` keyword.

```
// Create a new collection
var eventCollection = new EventCollection();
```

The next step is to add the event that you want to listen to. It needs the element, the type of event and the function to call when the event is triggered.

```
eventCollection.append(element, 'click', function() {});
```

Now your events are in the collection and stored, but they are not yet listening to the events. Use the `.listen()` method to loop over all the events in the collection and listen for them.

```
eventCollection.listen();
```

And whenever you want to stop listening to events in your collection, then use the following.

```
eventCollection.stopListening();
```