# Loop, passing a function as a parameter, argument of that function is always the last one. How to use bind()?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to [add an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to buttons which are generated in a browser extension. There are many buttons so it is done inside a loop, and the event handler of the button needs an argument (otherwise, all buttons will do the same thing).

```
for (....)
{
    ....
    var arg = createArgument(...);
    ....
    var myButton = document.createElement('button');
    myButton.addEventListner('click', function(){myButtonClick(arg)});
    ....
}

function myButtonClick(arg)
{
```

I used a method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/256763/455796) to pass an argument to the function, but the problem is that the `arg` for all buttons is set to the last value of `arg` at the last iteration of the `for` loop. A comment in that answer says that I have to use `bind()`, but I could understand how. In my case, how should I use `bind()` so that each button's event listener would have a different `arg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Using a function to create a new scope and bind that scope to the current `arg` value
2. Using `bind` to bind the current `arg` value as `this` inside the function

Here's how that works:

```
for (....) {
  ....
  var arg = createArgument(...);
  ....
  createButtonWithListener(arg);
  ....
}

function createButtonWitListener(arg) {
  var myButton = document.createElement('button');
  myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){ myButtonClick(arg) });
}
```

This works, because `createListener` gets called with the current value of `arg` and the value is copied into the scope of `createListener`.

The variation with using `bind` would bind `this` and the arguments inside the bound function to the values you pass, so it could work like this:

```
for (....) {
  ....
  var arg = createArgument(...);
  ....
  var myButton = document.createElement('button');
  myButton.addEventListener('click', function(boundArg){ myButtonClick(boundArg) }.bind(myButton, arg));
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to use bind is simply to call `myButtonClick.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]]])`: the first parameter is the value you want the function to refer to when you use the `this` keyword within the function and any other parameter after would be passed to the function as a normal argument.

In your case if you don't need to use `this` within your function you could simply do `myButton.addEventListener('click', myButtonClick.bind(null, arg);`

If you don't need to use your arg(s) outside of the loop and the functions I'd probably declare them as `let arg` rather than `var` that way they only appear within the loop.