# Passing multiple arguments and event to event handler using bind()

Tags: javascript

I want to use the `.bind` solution to implement event handler as per some latest solution in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function).

However, suppose my original handler is as following:

```
const clickHandler = (arg1, arg2) => {
   ...do stuff...
}

let var1 = "text1"
let var2 = "text2"
myButton.addEventListener("click", clickHandler.bind(null, var1, var2))
```

If I need to add a line like this, which requires the `event` argument, to the handler:

```
const clickHandler = (arg1, arg2) => {
   event.stopPropagation()
   ...do stuff...
}
```

If I do without using `.bind`, this would work:

```
const clickHandler = (arg1, arg2) => {
   ...do stuff...
}

let var1 = "text1"
let var2 = "text2"
myButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   event.stopPropagation()
   clickHandler(var1, var2)
})
```

But if I want to make it concise using `.bind`, how should I pass `event` into the handler? Thanks.

Comment: You can't rebind `this` in an arrow function. see: [can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308121/can-you-bind-this-in-an-arrow-function)

Comment: I know. So how do I include this line ```event.stopPropagation()``` in the handler function, so that can keep using this line ```myButton.addEventListener("click", clickHandler.bind(null, var1, var2))```? Basically I am trying to avoid using the arrow function as the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any arguments passed to `bind()` after the first are *prepended* to the arguments provided to the function when it is created, in this case `event`. This means that in the resulting bound callback the `event` will be the last argument the callback receives, rather than the first as is normal if not using bind. `this` remains unchanged as it is an arrow function.

If you are passing a consistent, known number of arguments in each `bind()` you can access them directly.

```
const clickHandler = (arg1, arg2, event) => {
...
}
```

Otherwise, if the number of bound arguments will vary you can access the `event` by retrieving the last element from the `arguments` iterator.

```
const clickHandler = (...args) => {
  const event = args.pop();
...
}
```

```js
const myButton = document.getElementById('button');

const clickHandler = (...args) => {
  const event = args.pop();
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log('args: ', args);
}

let var1 = "text1"
let var2 = "text2"

myButton.addEventListener("click", clickHandler.bind(null, var1, var2));
```

```html
<button type='button' id='button'>Button</button>
```

Per [the MDN documentation for `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, **with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called**.