# How to bind event to callable in addEventListener('event', callable.bind(???))

Tags: javascript, bind, addeventlistener

## EDIT 1

This question was closed almost immediately, since it's supposed to be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function). I beg to differ since the "original" question is about general argument binding, where this question (correctly) resolves a new issue via @Phil's comment. I believe that `.bind` prepending arguments before the *hidden* argument `event` on which you may then call `event.preventDefault()` is not common knowledge for all. For other's sake, I believe this question will stay open.

## EDIT 2

Another knowledge bomb (no sarcasm) from @Phil. In original question it is shown, that instead of `.addEventListener('event', callable.bind(this, data))` a possibly clearer way would be `.addEventListener('event', e => callable(e, data))` meaning using an intermediate anonymous function that you may put arguments into. A bonus here is that any data fetched (e.g. from a form) is fetched at the time of triggering event, which is clearly advantageous.

## ORIGINAL QUESTION

I likely didn't do the title rightly, so please comment a more appropriate one for me to edit.

Best explaining with an example.

This works:

```html
<script>
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        name: form.name.value,
    };
    fetch('logics-url.php', {
            ...,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(d => console.log(d))
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
});
</script>
```

Then I need the same `logic-url.php` called with different (additional) data when a `button` outside of the `form` is clicked.

First I extracted the callable from inside of the `addEventListener` and this still works:

```html
<script>
const callable = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        name: form.name.value,
    };
    fetch('logics-url.php', {
            ...,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(d => console.log(d))
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
form.addEventListener('submit', callable);
button.addEventListener('click', callable); // button *is* defined in this scope
</script>
```

Now I want to send different data these two `addEventListener`s and this where it fails me.

```html
<script>
const callable = (e, data) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Removed data here
    fetch('logics-url.php', {
            ...,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(d => console.log(d))
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
}

const data1 = {
    name: form.name.value,
};
form.addEventListener('submit', callable.bind(null, data1));

const data2 = {
    name: form.name.value,
    trigger: 1,
};
button.addEventListener('click', callable.bind(this, data2));
</script>
```

I foolishly tried binding `e`, when it does not exist yet, so I removed it. Then (as you can see) I tried binding `null` and `this` and they both resulted in error:

```
# console
Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined at callable
```

I tried different variations but most resulted in the above error.

I also tried passing just `dataN` as a lone parameter and it resulted in:

```
# console
POST {...}/logics-url.php 400 (Bad Request)
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Do I *have* to duplicate my code or is there another way?

Comment: `bind` just binds the `this` context. An Event's `this` context is called in the context of to the Element which it belongs to. You want to do like `someElement.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ yourFunc.call(someContext, arg); } });`

Comment: Your issue is that `Function.prototype.bind()` **prepends** arguments. Prepending `data` means that `callable` should be defined with args `(data, e)`

Comment: @StackSlave `Function.prototype.bind()` can also prepend function arguments. For example `((...args) => console.log(...args)).bind(null, 1, 2)(3)` will log "1 2 3"

Comment: Note that the `EventObject` is the only argument passed to an EventListener, though.

Comment: [[1]] I don't know why this question was closed, because the "original" one is asking just about normal argument binding, and *not* about the `e.preventDefault()` intricacy. [[2]] @Phil you're the man! I had no idea that the arguments are prepended. Although I now realized that I need to update `let data1` and `let data2` on input, since it (logically) get form inputs on page load, hence they are empty strings. Thank you.

Comment: I've added another duplicate that I believe answers your questions regarding `Function.prototype.bind()`. Also, I don't know what you mean by _"hidden argument `event`"_. The arguments passed to the event handler are explained [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback)... _"the callback accepts a single parameter: an object based on `Event` describing the event that has occurred"_

Comment: FYI, there's nothing wrong with having a question closed as a duplicate. It helps others find answers to their similar problems by increasing the possible search results

Comment: After your explanation I cannot argue with that. If you feel (he he) that the Q should be deleted, I will do so. Otherwise I provided explanations in the beginning of OP. EDIT: A bit late... never mind.