# Changing Iframe size by click event listener not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the iframe size by clicking the button by using the click event listener. But the iframe auto runs the function and I haven't even clicked the button...

Someone said this is a duplicate of [How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function) but I don't see where is this even related???

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

function change(w) {
   iframe.style.width = `${w}px`;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', change(150));
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>Change</button>
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your event listener function like so

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => change(150));
```

OR

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() { change(150) });
```

`addEventListener` expects a function definition and not a function call as second argument.

For more read: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: Can you elaborate more please, what is the `()` means here? Why do I need to create a new arrow function then put the `change` function inside it???

Comment: @nakar20966 I edited the answer, you shouldn't call a function inside addEventlistner like you are doing here `btn.addEventListener('click', change(150));`. You are supposed to pass a function definition