# how to use arguments with eventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I need to upgrade from "onclick" to "eventListener" but I need to keep the passing of arguments. How do I pass arguments when using "eventListener"? The following is the HTML and JavaScript code. Thanks.

```
<tbody>
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, nombre, signo_solar FROM horoscopos") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
                        
if (mysqli_num_rows($query)==0){
echo "<td colspan='3'>No hay horóscopos que mostrar. Prueba a añadir uno en 'Crear entrada' del menú superior.</td>";
}else{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { // Mientras haya elementos en el array
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[nombre]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[signo_solar]</td>";

    echo "<td>
          <button class='btn btn-danger' id='EditButton' onclick='editEntry($row[id])'>Editar</button>
          <button class='btn btn-danger' id='DeleteButton' onclick=\"deleteEntry($row[id],'$row[nombre]','$row[signo_solar]')\">Eliminar</button>
          </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
}
?>
</tbody>
```

the javascript:

```
function editEntry(id){
    ...
}
function deleteEntry(id, nombre, signo){
    ...
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.getElementById("EditButton").addEventListener("click", editEntry);
    document.getElementById("DeleteButton").addEventListener("click", deleteEntry);
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass arguments when using unobtrusive event handlers. Instead you can use `data` attributes to store your metadata within the element and read it back when the event fires.

In addition, note that you should *never* use `id` attributes when looping to create repeated content. It will cause duplicates which is invalid. You should use a common `class` in this case.

Here's a working example with the above guidelines implemented:

```js
const editButtonHandler = e => {
  const row = e.target.closest('tr');
  const rowId = row.dataset.rowid;
  console.log(`Editing rowId: ${rowId}`);
  // your logic here...
}

const deleteButtonHandler = e => {
  const row = e.target.closest('tr');
  const rowId = row.dataset.rowid;
  const rowNumber = row.dataset.rownumber;
  const rowSigno = row.dataset.signo;
  console.log(`Deleting rowId: ${rowId} / number: ${rowNumber} / signo: ${rowSigno}`);
    
  // your logic here... AJAX?
  
  row.remove();
}

document.querySelectorAll('.edit-button').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', editButtonHandler));
document.querySelectorAll('.delete-button').forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', deleteButtonHandler));
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-rowid="id1" data-rownumber="num1" data-signo="foo">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>signo_solar 1</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger edit-button">Editar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger delete-button">Eliminar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr data-rowid="id2" data-rownumber="num2" data-signo="bar">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>signo_solar 2</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger edit-button">Editar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger delete-button">Eliminar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but the table doesn't have a fixed size, it depends on how many relations does the database have.

Comment: Which is exactly why this pattern is used. The above code will work for a `<table>` of any length, so long as you keep the HTML of each row in the same structure - ie. containing the `data` attributes you need to read.

Comment: eventListener don't work

Comment: It clearly does as you can see in the example in my answer. Have you re-created the solution above correctly in your local version? Check the console for errors

Comment: This would've been better written on the duplicate...

Answer (score -2):

Here is the reference implementation for you.

```
<tbody>
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id, nombre, signo_solar FROM horoscopos") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
                        
if (mysqli_num_rows($query)==0){
echo "<td colspan='3'>No hay horóscopos que mostrar. Prueba a añadir uno en 'Crear entrada' del menú superior.</td>";
}else{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { // Mientras haya elementos en el array
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[nombre]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[signo_solar]</td>";

    echo "<td>
          <button class='btn btn-danger' id='EditButton' data-id='"+$row['id']+"'>Editar</button>
          <button class='btn btn-danger' id='DeleteButton' data-id='"+$row['id']+"' data-nombre='"+$row['nombre']+"' data-signo='"+$row['signo_solar']+"'>Eliminar</button>
          </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
}
?>
</tbody>
```

And the JS will be:

```
function editEntry(event){
    var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
}
function deleteEntry(event){
    var id = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
    var nombre = event.target.getAttribute("data-nombre");
    var signo = event.target.getAttribute("data-signo");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.getElementById("EditButton").addEventListener("click", editEntry);
    document.getElementById("DeleteButton").addEventListener("click", deleteEntry);
})
```

Comment: data-id='"+$row[id]+"' sysntax returns a "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered"

Comment: Should it not be `$row['id']`?

Comment: ... and also `$row['nombre']` etc?

Comment: The original sample code is not complete and it's not related to the issue he asked. I updated my code.