# Calling javascript document event listener from blazor server c# without event repeating but maintaining dotnetreference

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor server - i want to use keyboard keys to control the screen.

1.I pass the dotNetReference to my javascript function.

```
    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        
        var dotNetReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JsFunctions.addKeyboardListenerEvent", dotNetReference);

    }
```

2. I run the javascript and return a call to razor page.

When it's an anonymous function, it repeats the call however many times keyup has happened. When the function call with the eventListener is defined, I lose the dotNetReference but it correctly runs once!

3. I am so close but cannot figure out how to persist the dotNetReference so it can invoke the C# method

anonymous

```
    addKeyboardListener: function (dotNetReference) {
        

        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
            /*document.removeEventListener('keyup');*/
            if (event.key == 7) {
                dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('Prev');
            }
            if (event.key == 8) {
                dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('Next');
            }
            if (event.key == 3) {
                dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('NavigateToOverviewPage');
            }
        });
```

defined
addKeyboardListener: function (dotNetReference) {

```
    document.addEventListener('keyup', myFunction) 


    function myFunction(event) {

        // Calls a method by name with the [JSInokable] attribute (above)
        var dotNetReference = dotNetReference
        if (event.key == 7) {
            dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('Prev');
        }
        if (event.key == 8) {
            dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('Next');
        }
        if (event.key == 3) {
            dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('NavigateToOverviewPage');
        }
    }

}
```

```
C#
[JSInvokable]
public  void Next()
{
    ClearMessages();
}
```

There must be a way to persist the dotNetReference but I cannot figure it out and must be missing an obvious way to go about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got it to work thanks to this link: [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256754/how-to-pass-arguments-to-addeventlistener-listener-function)

1. keep this:

```
    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        
        var dotNetReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JsFunctions.addKeyboardListenerEvent", dotNetReference);
    
    }
```

2. store the dotNetReference as a property of the object you addEventListener to (in my case document):

```
    def: function test(dotNetReference) {
        document.dotNetRef = dotNetReference;
        document.addEventListener('keyup', abc)
    }
```

3. abc can now access the dotNetReference:

```
    abc: function myFunction1(e) {
        dn = e.currentTarget.dotNetRef;
        // Calls a method by name with the [JSInokable] attribute (above)
    
        if (e.key == 7) {
            dn.invokeMethodAsync('Prev');
        }
        if (e.key == 8) {
            dn.invokeMethodAsync('Next');
        }
        if (e.key == 3) {
            dn.invokeMethodAsync('NavigateToOverviewPage');
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this add an event listener for each render? So if your view changed state 3 times, causing 3 renders + the initial render, you would be invoking your C# functions 4 times for every keyboard event. I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to aciheve, but you probably only want to add the event listener on the first render?

Comment: in my second code block in question (first javascript block) that was exactly what was happening. however, in my answer i defined the function and removed it from addListener call. Since the addListener was only called OnAfterFirstRender, it only registered that one time.  my issue from there was passing the dotnetreference to the now defined function. once i attached it as a property of document in my answer, that was available, thus registering the listener with defined function one time, then calling that listener once per keyup!